# from_tensor_slices returns ValueError when passing two numpy arrays as arguments

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've got two numpy arrays: images_ar (data) and  categorical_y_ar (labels).

Both consist of dtype('uint8').

Shape of categorical_y_ar is (978, 126).

Shape of images_ar is (978, 224, 224, 3)

When trying to build a dataset with:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images_ar, categorical_y_ar)
```

I get the following traceback:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [50], in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(images_ar, categorical_y_ar)
> 2 dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(batch_size)
> 4 val_size = int( num_classes* 0.2)
>
> File
> ~.conda\envs\sklearn-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:814,
> in DatasetV2.from_tensor_slices(tensors, name)
> 736 @staticmethod
> 737 def from_tensor_slices(tensors, name=None):
> 738   """Creates a `Dataset` whose elements are slices of the given tensors.
> 739
> 740   The given tensors are sliced along their first dimension. This operation    (...)
> 812     Dataset: A `Dataset`.
> 813   """
> --> 814   return TensorSliceDataset(tensors, name=name)
>
> File
> ~.conda\envs\sklearn-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:4728, in TensorSliceDataset.**init**(self, element, is_files, name)    4719
> for t in self._tensors[1:]:    4720
> batch_dim.assert_is_compatible_with(    4721
> tensor_shape.Dimension(    4722
> tensor_shape.dimension_value(t.get_shape()[0])))    4724
> variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.tensor_slice_dataset(    4725
> self._tensors,    4726
> output_shapes=structure.get_flat_tensor_shapes(self._structure),
> 4727     is_files=is_files,
> -> 4728     metadata=self._metadata.SerializeToString())    4729 super(TensorSliceDataset, self).**init**(variant_tensor)
>
> File
> ~.conda\envs\sklearn-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:668,
> in DatasetV2._metadata(self)
> 666 """Helper for generating dataset metadata."""
> 667 metadata = dataset_metadata_pb2.Metadata()
> --> 668 if self._name:
> 669   metadata.name = _validate_and_encode(self._name)
> 670 return metadata
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Please help me to figure out why this error pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the data as a set or list not as a single entity to the tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slice(), as shown below

```
x_train = np.random.randn(978, 224, 224, 3)
y_train = np.random.randint(0,127, size=(978, 127))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

print(next(iter(dataset.take(1))))
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=float64, numpy= ...
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. It looks like i should have passed a tuple ((x_train, y_train)). And i passed (x_train, y_train) instead.